# Consequences of Keras running out of memory

Tags: tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, gpu

in case this question is off topic here, please feel free to refer to another StackExchange site. :-)

I am working with Keras and have quite limited memory on my GPU (GeForce GTX 970, ~4G). So as a consequence I run out of memory (OOM) working with Keras having a batch size set above a certain level. Lowering the batch size I don't have this issue, but Keras outputs the following warnings:

```
2019-01-02 09:47:03.173259: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.57GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:03.211139: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.68GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:03.268074: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.95GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:03.685032: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.39GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:03.732304: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.56GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:03.850711: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.39GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:03.879135: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.48GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:03.963522: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.42GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:03.984897: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.47GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2019-01-02 09:47:04.058733: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.08GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

What do these warnings mean for me as a user? What are those performance gains? Does it mean that it simply computes faster or do I even get better results in terms of a better validation loss?

In my setup I use Keras with Tensorflow backend and tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0.

Comment: Are you using `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu`?

Comment: edited the question with the necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the training will experience some loss of efficiency in terms of speed, as the GPU can not be used for some operations. The result of the loss should not be affected, though.

In order to avoid this issue the best practice is to reduce the batch size to make efficient use of available GPU memory.

Comment: So one should reduce batch_size down to the amount which doesn't trigger this message? I personally get the message only at the very beginning of the training, and then it doesn't appear again.